# Schengen visa Czech Republic travel to France

Tags: france, schengen-visas

I have a valid Schengen visa for the Czech Republic for business. I now need to travel this time from my home country to France.

Will the same Schengen visa be valid?

Comment: It looks like you have two accounts. It's easy to [get them merged](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can edit your question without needing approval, accept an answer and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an unexpired multiple-entry visa, it's valid for any country in the Schengen zone, which includes France.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the visa is for *multiple entries*, and that you've completed the trip to Czechia you got it for, then: Yes, you can use it for travel to anywhere in the Schengen Area without any further formalities.

Comment: We answered at the same time, to the second. 

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Yours got the lower post ID, so I'll delete mine.

Comment: This answer contains some information the other does not have, so I prefer this to be visible to the OP.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yessss! I win! But I don't think there's any need to delete yours, especially as it's slightly more detailed.